# Variable value is not set in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller is:

```
bool isThreadComplete = false;
public ActionResult generateDoc()
{            
    Thread thread = new Thread(threadSleep);
    thread.Start();
    return Json(true);
}
public void threadSleep()
{
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
    isThreadComplete = true;
}
public ActionResult callThreadSleep() {
    return Json(isThreadComplete);
}
```

when I call `callThreadSleep` using ajax then it doesnot set value of variable `isThreadComplete` even after 30sec..any suggestion?

Comment: Each request by default gets their own controller instance and you shouldn't start threads from controllers. What is this supposed to do? Are you trying to implement a "background worker"? Then search on that, something like "asp.net mvc background task", and you'll find the proper way to do so. There's more than enough written on that subject to repeat it here.

Comment: @CodeCaster I want `isThreadComplete` value that will do further process onward

Comment: @debin, what CodeCaster is saying is that your ajax request will be using a different instance of the controller to any other calls to it, therefore the isThreadComplete variable would never be anything but the value it's initialised as when you make the request.  To do something like this, you're going to need a variable (that I personally wouldn't hold in your controller) that's held across requests, either as a static variable held in a separate class, or using something like Session and some sort of per-session locking mechanism to keep it threadsafe.

Comment: @ChrisDisley thnx I solved it my interlock

Comment: Static variables will break when multiple users simultaneously use this code.